# Reading a File with PHP gives 500 error

Tags: php, mp3, readfile

I have a script which reads a mp3 file with readfile() (I have also tried fread() with a loop). And on one particular file I am getting a 500 error. All other files seem to read just fine.

When I review the error log on my server I notice I am getting a PHP memory error when ever this particular file is attempted to be read.

Can anyone give me some pointers as to what might be going on?

Comment: Sounds like you're running out of memory - How big is the file? What are your server's memory limits?

Comment: Can you post the code with what you're trying to do with the file? How big is the file? And how big is your memory_limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already pointed out the problem - PHP is running out of memory.  Maximum memory usage in PHP is limited by an ini setting.

You can set it at runtime at the top of your script with [ini_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php):

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '64M');
```

Or you can set it in your [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) file so it takes effect for *all scripts*:

```
memory_limit = 64M;
```

Finally, you can see the memory used by *the currently executing script* with [`memory_get_usage()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php)

Comment: The second example you gave was for a `.htaccess` file, not a php.ini file.

Comment: Sorry about that. Fixing it now.

Comment: This really didnt fix my issue. I did something else. Used a script called smartreadfile.php which I think reads the file in as chunks. Anyway this was the best formatted answer from my experiences now.

Answer (score 0):

The mp3 file is of a larger filesize than `memory_limit`. You'll need to increase the amount of memory PHP can access if you want to read from this mp3 file.

If you have access to the php.ini file, you can find `memory_limit = 16M ;` and replace the value with however much memory you need.

If you don't have php.ini access and you do have .htaccess access, add:

`php_value memory_limit 16M`

and replace the value.

If you have neither, try compressing the mp3 file or otherwise reducing the amount of memory it will take for you to perform this action. Try clearing variables which are unused and take up large amounts of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Well, php is probably running out of memory before completing the script. You can just increase the memory php is allowed to run by changing the memory_limit option in your php.ini.

Comment: Just a note, IMO asking questions directed towards the OP are more suited for comments, not answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the execution time:
set_time_limit(300); //300 seconds
ini_set('memory_limit','16M'); //increase to some value like 16 MB

Comment: That changes time limit, not memory

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it exceeds maximum memory. This can be adjusted in the php.ini, check here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit